# Rails and Hobo with Single Table Inheritance problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, single-table-inheritance, hobo

I'm getting an error when running `db:setup` for my Hobo project with a clean database. I have two models, A and B, where B extends A through single-table-inheritance. Creating everything works. But if I start with a fresh database, rake fails with an error:

```
$ rake db:setup
...
rake aborted!
Table as does not exist
```

Here are the steps I went through to reproduce this. First, create the Hobo app:

```
$ hobo testproject
```

Create the first model, `A`:

```
$ ruby script/generate hobo_model_resource a name:string type:string
```

Setup database.yml, generate and execute the migration:

```
$ ruby script/generate hobo_migration
```

Create the second model, `B`:

```
$ruby script/generate hobo_model_resource b
```

Edit the `B` model to extend `A`:

```
class B < A

  # --- Permissions --- #
  def create_permitted?
    acting_user.administrator?
  end

  def update_permitted?
    acting_user.administrator?
  end

  def destroy_permitted?
    acting_user.administrator?
  end

  def view_permitted?(field)
    true
  end
end
```

Generate and run the migration:

```
$ ruby script/generate hobo_migration
```

Voila. All works fine. Now, if I delete all the tables and run `db:setup`, it fails:

```
$ rake db:setup
...
rake aborted!
Table as does not exist
```

Following the suggestions at [Ruby on Rails Single Table Inheritance (STI) and unit test problem (with PostgreSQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646391/ruby-on-rails-single-table-inheritance-sti-and-unit-test-problem-with-postgres), I tried removing `test/fixtures/as.yml` and `test/fixtures/bs.yml`, but that didn't help.

hobo 0.9.103
rails 2.3.5
rake 0.8.7
jruby 1.4.0RC1

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in Hobo:

http://groups.google.com/group/hobousers/browse_thread/thread/2160e78762791946

According to Matt Jones:

> The trace has the automatic scope code trying to see if  inherited_without_inheritable_attributes is a column, which hits the
>   DB and dies.

He suggests adding:

```
return unless table_exists?
```

at the very beginning of the `column` method (line 211 of `hobofields/lib/hobo_fields/model_extensions.rb`).

Comment: Note that this was fixed on 1/24/2010 and is in the latest release candidate.

Answer (score 0):

I followed all of your steps, and everything worked fine. Have you tried `rake db:schema:load`?

```
hobo 0.9.104
rails 2.3.5
rake 0.8.6
ruby 1.8.6
```